# There is no result with react

Tags: reactjs

[image]This is my first react code to try react work in my laptop but it does not work

As you can see in the picture, the shadow ends before . The shadow must be covering all script tags. I do not know why!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/react.js"></script>
    <script src="js/react-dom.js"></script>
 <script src="js/browser.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <div id = "dome"></div>

    <script type='text/jsx'>
 
        ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello React </h1>,document.getElementById("dome");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how are you transpiling jsx?

Comment: I do not know what do you mean. I just try to do the first tutorial. I download react files as seen in the code but it does not work. I use to call react.js via online but also did not work https://react-cn.github.io/react/downloads.html

Answer (score 1):

Your code have a syntax error, bracket of render function is not closed.

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello React </h1>,document.getElementById("dome");
```

Use this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello React </h1>,document.getElementById("dome"));
```

**Edit:** If you want use JSX, you should use `text/babel` in script type and be sure to import `browser.js` file.

```
<script type='text/babel'>
    ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello React </h1>, document.getElementById("dome"));
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it did not work. I edit the question

Comment: I edited my answer. Check out. Problem related to script type.

Answer (score 1):

`JSX` is not valid javascript, so it has to be transpiled first. this is why you get the error there. The source you mentioned is somewhat outdated, and is not the origin actually.

Just go with the actual tutorial here: 
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html